# Wordpress mobile homepage lost formatting during server migration

Tags: wordpress, mobile, migration

I recently migrated my wordpress theme to blog.nearlynewlywed.com.  The site renders fine on desktop, however, the homepage on mobile has lost all formatting.  Just the homepage.  Interior pages on mobile are fine.

It looks like the site is displaying a mobile theme template but I'm not sure and honestly I can't figure out how to identify the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are using some conditionals to select the correct style sheets, and some of them could be missing or pointing to a wrong url.

Use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and in the "Net" tab check if something is missing or giving any error.